# How to unit test Spring Integration’s int-file:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: unit-testing, spring-integration, spring-integration-file

I have a simple Spring Integration flow where I read XML files from a given directory, and send their content to another channel and do other processing.

After the processing is done, I need to move the input file in an archive/error directory.

`file-integration.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <import resource="transaction-manager-configuration.xml"/>

  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties"/>

  <int:channel id="inputFileChannel"/>

  <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inputFileChannel"
                                    directory="${inputDir}"
                                    filename-pattern="*.xml">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000">
      <int:transactional transaction-manager="txManager" synchronization-factory="syncFactory"/>
    </int:poller>
  </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

  <int-file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="inputFileChannel"
                                       output-channel="contentChannel"/>

  <int:channel id="contentChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="inputFileSuccessChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="inputFileErrorChannel"/>

  <!-- Move file after being processed -->

  <int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit channel="inputFileSuccessChannel"/>
    <int:after-rollback channel="inputFileErrorChannel"/>
  </int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

  <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inputFileSuccessChannel"
                                     directory="${archiveDir}"
                                     delete-source-files="true"/>

  <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inputFileErrorChannel"
                                     directory="${errorDir}"
                                     delete-source-files="true"/>

</beans>
```

My questions:

1. In a unit test context, how can I create & push an **in-memory** file in `inputFileChannel`, **without relying on the real filesystem**?
2. How can I test that my input file has been pushed to `inputFileSuccessChannel` / `inputFileErrorChannel`? How to mock the `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter/>`?
3. Again in my unit test context without relying on the real filesystem, how can I test that my **in-memory** input file has been deleted (as configured with the `delete-source-files="true"` statements)?

At the moment, I have a JUnit 5 test class `FileIntegrationTest.java`:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@SpringIntegrationTest
public class FileIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  MessageChannel inputFileChannel;

  @Autowired
  QueueChannel contentTestChannel;

  @Test
  void shouldReadInputFile_thenMoveIt() {
    // arrange
    File inputFile = new … // question 1
    Message<File> inputMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();

    // act
    inputFileChannel.send(inputMessage);

    // assert
    assertThat(contentTestChannel.getQueueSize(), is(1));
    assertThat(inputFileSuccessChannel contains my input file); // question 2
    assertThat(inputFile has been deleted); // question 3
  }
}
```

And its context file `FileIntegrationTest-context.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

  <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/file-integration.xml"/>

  <int:bridge input-channel="contentChannel"
              output-channel="contentTestChannel"/>
  <int:channel id="contentTestChannel">
    <int:queue/>
  </int:channel>
</beans>
```

The official Spring [Testing support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/testing.html) page mentions the use of mocks, but I’m confused how to use it. I’ve checked out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples as well, but I could find a proper solution.

Comment: I have the exact same requirement, did you find anything on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I gave Spring Integration a try, but I switched back to Apache Camel, with which I have more experience. If I need to work again on integration, I may try Spring Integration again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Add a channel interceptor to the channel, or see [the documentation about mocking endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/testing.html#testing-mocks).
3. If you send a test file to the channel; you can check to see if still exists when the test completes.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your reply. I think you misread my first question  I also updated my question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "in-memory" File. Create the file in a temp directory and send it.

Comment: @GaryRussell actually there is such thing as "in-memory filesystem"...

Comment: @Mafor Are you thinking about [`jimfs`](https://github.com/google/jimfs)? Do you think it would be suitable for my tests? And most importantly, am I overengineering my test?

Comment: @MorganCourbet Just an idea, I'm not sure if it would be applicable. And indeed, it might be kind of overengineering.

Comment: `>there is such thing` Sure; I meant in the standard JVM; but, whatever, it's much simpler to use the real filesystem for tests like this.